# javascript index() of form inputs and selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of inputs and selects mixed together in an html form:

```
<th><input type="text" id="bGroup" name="search_group"   /></th>
<th><input type="text" id="bEvent" name="search_event"   /></th>
<th><input type="text" id="bBenefactor" name="search_benefactor"   /></th>
<th><select name="search_status" id="bStatus">      
        <option value=""></option>      
        <option value="RS">RS</option>                  
        <option value="CAN">Cancelled</option>                  
        <option value="ICR">ICR</option>                    
        <option value="HLD">Holding</option>            
        <option value="DEN">Denied</option>                 
    </select>
 </th>
<th><input type="text" id="bGiving" name="search_giving"   /></th>
```

I am trying to use a JQuery function to call the index of the form element.
This works fine if I'm only using form inputs and not selects like so:

```
$("tfoot input").keyup( function () {
        /* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */  
        oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $("tfoot input").index(this) );
    } );
```

If i want to use both form input elements, I have to manually assign indexes like this:

```
$("tfoot input#bGroup").keyup( function () {
        /* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */  
        //alert($("tfoot input").index(this));
        oTable.fnFilter( this.value, 1 );
    } );
... 
$("tfoot select#bStatus").on('change',  function () {
        /* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */  
        //  alert($("tfoot select").parent().index(this));
        oTable.fnFilter( this.value, 4 );
    } );
```

Which is not to my advantage.

What I would like to do is have both form elements index together so I do not have to manually assign rows/write a bunch of functions.
I tried using a fieldset but I didn't have much luck.

```
$("tfoot fieldset").on('keyup change', function () {
        /* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */  
        oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $("tfoot fieldset").index(this) );
    } );
```

Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `$("input, select", "tfoot").index(this)`

Comment: that was it, guess it was easy, make an answer and ill give you credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select both input and select elements, and get the index based on that like so:

```
 $("input, select", "tfoot").index(this)
```